# Why is there not an IntegerArrayInputStream class?

Tags: java, int, byte, inputstream

I'm wondering why is there no class for `IntegerArrayInputStream`, because I have an `int` array to be able to write int's to an image file format. I also see how there is a lot of confusion about converting ints to bytes.

Comment: Note that a `ByteBuffer` might be appropriate here.

Comment: Doesn't an integer value represent a completely different value for a byte?

Comment: If you do end up writing something on your own using a ByteArrayInputStream etc, keep in mind that you may need to correct for "endian"-ness. (an integer in java is not necessarily / often is not equivalent at the binary level to an integer elsewhere)

Comment: `ByteBuffer` has a [`putInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putInt(int)) method that converts an `int` to bytes which it adds to the `ByteBuffer`. You can then convert the `ByteBuffer` to a `byte[]`.

Comment: I did that exactly, and I am returning just 0 (zeros) when looping through the byte array?

Answer (score 3):

There's a limit to how much any function library can provide; at some point they have to say "If you need one, write one or obtain one from some package other than the JRE." What you're proposing is not something which is needed especially frequently (unlike ByteArrayInputStream, which *is* frequently used), nor is it something which is especially hard to implement, so I'm not surprised it didn't make the cut.

Answer (score 1):

The reason there's a `ByteArrayInputStream` is mainly just to allow people to dump entire string buffers (which are easily turned into byte arrays) to files. There already exist Java libraries that implement this for the sole purpose of Images. But byte arrays are more widely applicable than integer arrays to anything that needs I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a `DataInputStream` class and a `BufferedInputStream` class which together do 90% of the work, and which also cover bytes, chars, shorts, longs, floats, and doubles, without requiring the addition of *N* classes.

You don't have to add a class for every feature you need.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but if you want to write ints to bytes, can't you use

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    int x = 555;
    dos.writeInt(x);
    dos.close();

    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    int y = dis.readInt();
    System.out.println(y);
```

?

Comment: This writes `43` to the stream. ; )

Answer (score 0):

I put a comment above but I decided to make a full blown answer as well.  Part of the reason is that the Integer class is a Java specific thing.  If you dont care about portability and just want to read/write an Integer, Integer is serializable and you can treat it as an object or as a string value.  It's not efficient but it works.  If you *do* care about portability, ints as primitives are vague things.  They can vary in number of bytes, be signed or unsigned and endianness (byte ordering) or any combination of these things. Byte arrays on the other hand are for the most part always represented the same way everywhere ("bit-endianness" is a virtually non existent concern.  most people will even say its a myth :) and can be safely read / written in a standard way.